# use redis connection in elixir genstage consumer

Tags: elixir, genstage

I have an example of genstage application, and in its consumers I need to use a connection with redis. And I do not understand how I need to pass this connection to handle_events.

If I write:

```
  defp connection do
    {:ok, conn} = Redix.start_link(host: "0.0.0.0", port: 6379)
    conn
  end
```

Then every time the connection is called inside the handle_events function, it will create a new connection.

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the `conn` in the `state` of the `GenStage` consumer (just like you would to in a `GenServer`, something like this:

```
defmodule C do
  use GenStage

  def start_link() do
    GenStage.start_link(C, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, conn} = Redis.start_link(...)
    {:consumer, conn}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, conn) do
    Redix.command!(conn, ...)

    {:noreply, [], conn}
  end
end
```

Here I'm creating the connection when the consumer is created. You can also create the connection higher up and pass it down to this if you want, like this:

```
defmodule C do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(conn) do
    GenStage.start_link(C, conn)
  end

  def init(conn) do
    {:consumer, conn}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, conn) do
    Redix.command!(conn, ...)

    {:noreply, [], conn}
  end
end
```